# MFC: How do I get the CView* of a tab in a CTabView?

Tags: mfc, tabcontrol, cview

I have a `CTabView` and add a tab like `AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView1), _T("View1"));`.  But how do I get a pointer to the created `CMyView1` class created in the tab?

TIA!!

Comment: You probably need to customize add view to get view pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
CMFCTabCtrl& MFCTabCtrl = YourTabView.GetTabControl();
for(int i = 0;i < MFCTabCtrl.GetTabsNum();++i)
{
    CMyView1* pView = (CMyView1*)MFCTabCtrl.GetTabWnd(i);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the MFC-MDI tab view Implementation, when you are talking about views, this is the easiest way.

Comment: where would you find that at?

Comment: Create a sample with the wizard. Select MDI format and Tabs-